# Яндекс oauth выдаёт ошибку invalid_scope

Tags: laravel, авторизация, oauth

Использую Socialite на Laravel 5.5, добавил туда Яндекс, но при переходе на страницу авторизации Яндекс говорит:

> Не удалось определить список запрашиваемых доступов (invalid_scope)

Запрос который генерируется:

```
https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?client_id=3fde0c613c4941aa9b2143247d560fb5&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgreenhoster.com%2Fauth%2Fyandex%2Fcallback&scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&state=6EILCMFrARHkCq5HFiV6aah8sRaAxU8GrcAisJrc
```

Яндекс провайдер:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Socialite\Two;

use Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;

class YandexProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * The separating character for the requested scopes.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeSeparator = ' ';

    /**
     * The scopes being requested.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $scopes = [
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase(
            'https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize', $state
        );
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return 'https://oauth.yandex.ru/token';
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
            'https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ],
        ]);
        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'nickname' => $user['login'],
            'name' => Arr::get($user, 'real_name'),
            'email' => Arr::get($user, 'default_email'),
            'avatar' => 'https://avatars.yandex.net/get-yapic/'.Arr::get($user, 'default_avatar_id').'/islands-200',
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenFields($code)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getTokenFields($code), [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если удалить содержимое массива

```
protected $scopes = [
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
    ];
```

то будут запрашиваться права, которые были выставлены в [настройках](https://oauth.yandex.ru/) приложения, и тогда всё работает!

Comment: Теперь Яндекс стал ругаться даже когда `scope` пустой. Надо вообще исключить параметр `scope` из url.

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy день назад приложение начало приложение выдавать ошибку invalid scope. не могу разобраться в чем причина, может у вас есть информация или ссылка? UPD: причем вчера даже отладочные токены не работали

Comment: @Spiffo собственно, в связи с этим я и написал свой комментарий. я убрал `scope=` из url, и заработало.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться как обнулить scope в авторизации с ASP NET, хорошо что ситуация немного прояснилась. Просто неожиданно изменилась отработка запроса авторизации, тех. под не ответил - думала Яндекс о таких изменениях сообщает.

Answer (score 0):

На Hybridauth 3.0 чтобы убрать scope нужно определить его как:

```
protected $scope = null;
```